# Karnaugh map dont-care case

Tags: boolean-expression, truthtable, karnaugh-map

I'm currently working with the following truth table

[image]

I need to get the karnaugh map from this table and a simulation gives me this

[image]

However when I manually do it I get this result (since X can be whatever you need)

[image]

I don't really know what I'm missing... I know it must be related to the X but what I studied says you don't really need to group all the X to get the result

What I'm currently doing is getting the group of 1s this way

1st group

0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0

this gives me a'b'd'

2nd group

0 1 1 1

this gives me a'bcd

3rd group

1 1 0 0

1 0 0 0

this gives me ac'd'

So yeah I'm not getting the same result of the simulation and I don't know why... I'm sure its something related to the don't care fields (X)

Comment: I have just added another K-map to my answer, indexed the same way as yours, depicting the same minimal DNF. Hopefully, now you will see, why is your solution different to the generated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solution is considered better, because **yours did not use the X in the bottom right corner to your advantage** - to gain a quad (each of the four corners forms it). Also the two solutions cannot be equivalent, because the X are evaluated differently - you took it as a zero, the other solution made it a part of the group of logical ones.

Your expression uses **two pairs and one single cell** and the other solution covers **one quad, one pair and one single cell**.

The X cells can be indeed either 1 or 0, but it is intended to use them **to find larger groups** of cells for the currently chosen output value (1/0).

You can use it in either way (as a zero or as a logical one), but then the minimal DNF and minimal CNF would not be fully equivalent to each other, because the X is kind of a shape-shifter:)

You can see in the following picture, that one of the Xs is used in both minimal forms - once as a zero, once as a logical one.

[image: Using the X in K-maps]

```
f_1 = ¬b·¬d + a·¬c·¬d + ¬a·b·c·d
f_0 = (c + ¬d)·(b + ¬d)·(¬a + ¬c)·(a + ¬b + d)
```

(Images were generated using latex.)